# Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet [MyController]

Tags: jsp, java-ee, tomcat, maven

Tengo un proyecto web maven con java 8, pero al momento de exportarlo o correrlo no me genera el compilado de todas las clases.

```
jun 25, 2019 11:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Marcando el servlet [MyController] como no disponible
jun 25, 2019 11:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet [MyController]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fariddroid.controller.MyController
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

No solo con este servlet sino con los otros 3 que tengo definidos.
Aqui el web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
        <welcome-file>admin2.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcURL</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maven_project?serverTimezone=UTC
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcUserName</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jdbcPassword</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>MyController</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fariddroid.controller.MyController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ControlPetType</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ControlPetType</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fariddroid.controller.ControlPetType
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ControlTipoMascota</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ControlTipoMascota</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fariddroid.controller.ControlTipoMascota
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControlPetType</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ControlPetType</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControlTipoMascota</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ControlTipoMascota</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Aquí el servlet

```
package com.fariddroid.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.fariddroid.dao.DaoPoolTest;
import com.fariddroid.dao.DaoTest;
import com.fariddroid.dao.DaoTipoMascota;
import com.fariddroid.model.TipoMascota;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller
 * @WebServlet("/Controller")
 */

public class MyController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    DaoTest daoTest;  
    DaoPoolTest daoPoolTest;
    DaoTipoMascota daoTipoMascta;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        //Se cargan los valores del archivo de configuración
        //apenas se crea el servlet
        String jdbcURL = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcURL");
        String jdbcUserName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcUserName");
        String jdbcPassword = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jdbcPassword");
        System.out.println(jdbcURL);
        try {
            daoTest = new DaoTest(jdbcURL, jdbcUserName, jdbcPassword);
            daoTipoMascta = new DaoTipoMascota(jdbcURL, jdbcUserName, jdbcPassword);
            daoPoolTest = new DaoPoolTest(jdbcURL, jdbcUserName, jdbcPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        if(daoTipoMascta.create(new TipoMascota("Perro"))) {
            System.out.println("Se crea mascota single connection");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Error al mascota singee connection");
        }

        if(daoPoolTest.create(new TipoMascota("Loro"))) {
            System.out.println("Se crea mascota loro pool connection");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Error al crear mascota loro pool connection");
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Y este es el pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.1xsd">
    <modelVersion>3.1</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fariddroid.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>maven_project Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>maven_project</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Ya he hecho maven clean, project clean, he borrado mil veces el servlet, he ensayado con apache 8.5 y 9, pero sale el mismo error. La verdad ya no se que hacer, he buscado el error en todas partes y no logro solucionarlo, de nuevo muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo empaquetas en maven y cómo despliegas en el tomcat?

Comment: El empaquetado lo hago en war, despliego desde elipse y también ensayo desde servidor real ubicando el war en la carpeta webapps y tampoco.

Comment: Abre el war y mira si los servlets estan dentro y bien compilados.

Comment: Están todas las las clases dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF\classes pero está el fuente de todas incluyendo los servlets en la ruta de paquetes creada (pero porque le marco la opción export source), pero no hay ningún compilado.

Comment: Esto lo explica todo ¿no? Si no hay clase compilada ...

Comment: La pregunta ahora es: ¿Por qué no las compila? si la estructura de las clases está bien src/main/java

Comment: No tengo a mano nada de maven, lo siento, a lo mejor mañana

Comment: dale amigo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @JhonArias por favor no modifiques tu pregunta colocando la solución, para eso tienes en la parte inferior la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 1):

El error era que no reconocia mi estructura de paquetes por lo cual no generaba los .class en la carpeta WEB-INF/classes

Para solucionarlo hice lo siguiente:

Click derecho sobre el proyecto -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly ->Add... 
Folder -> Next y una vez allí seleccionar el último nivel de paquetes
en mi caso fue src/main/java/com/fariddroid/

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: oi]

No olviden agregar las Maven Dependencies a: WEB-INF/lib en caso de que les de algún error con alguna de las dependencias de Maven.

Comment: Me alegro de que has solucionado el problema peo se me antoja una pregunta ¿cómo creaste el proyecto maven? Porque por lo que comentas me da la impresión que esto no era un proyecto maven aunque lo estuvieras compilando y empaquetando con maven.

Comment: Saludos, inicialmente como Dinamic Web Project, luego le di convertir a maven project.